# Why does my Node.js AWS Lambda Function Only Work Every Other Time?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

I have a Node.js Lambda function that makes a copy of a snapshot. The problem is that it only works every other time it is invoked. I think the problem is something to do with my not handling the asynchronous part of the code properly via async / await. But I can’t figure out what the problem is.

No error is ever caught. I've set the timeout value to 35 seconds which should be plenty. The logged output is identical, whether the snapshot is created or not.
**But the snapshot is only created the second time I run the function!?**

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Thanks.

Using the latest version of Node.js available in AWS.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'});
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
const dst_account = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
const src_account = "yyyyyyyyyyyy";

async function get_all_snapshots(owner){
    console.log("*** get_all_snapshots() entered");
     
    var params = {
       Filters: [{
         Name: "status", Values: [ "completed" ]
       }],
       MaxResults: 5,       // Minimum value, as just need the last one.
       OwnerIds: [ owner ]
     }; // end params
         
    try {
       var snapshots = await ec2.describeSnapshots(params).promise();
       return snapshots;
    } catch (err) {
        throw Error(err);
    }
} 

async function copy_snapshot(id){
 
    console.log("*** copy_snapshot() entered", id);
     
    var params = {
        Description: "Snapshot created by Lambda Function", 
        DestinationRegion: "eu-west-2", 
        SourceRegion: "eu-west-2", 
        SourceSnapshotId: id
    }; // end params
     
    try {
       var ss = await ec2.copySnapshot(params).promise();
       console.log("*** ec2.copySnapshot() call completed. ss: ", ss); // THIS NEVER APPEARS In The LOGS
       return ss;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("!!! copy_snapshots() Throwing Error: ", err);
        throw Error(err); // TODO: throwing for now, but could this be handled better?
    }
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    return get_all_snapshots(src_account)
    .then(snapshots => {      
        copy_snapshot(snapshots.Snapshots[0].SnapshotId) // *** Add return here to fix ***
        .then(r =>{
            console.log("**new ss:", r); // THIS NEVER APPEARS IN THE LOGS
        })
        console.log("*** exports.handler() Ending");
     })
     .catch((err)=>{
         console.log("*** get_all_snapshots() Error: ",err);
     }); // End get_snapshots() 
};
```

Comment: Actually I think I've found the problem. The call to `copy_snapshot()` should have the word `return` in front of it: `return copy_snapshot(snapshots.Snaptshots[0].SnapshotId)` - this makes it work as expected. But I've still no idea why I saw the behaviour I did. **Grateful for another pointers about whether I'm tackling this problem the right way.**